# bash: keytool: command not found in a Flutter Project

Tags: java, flutter

I am trying to following the steps to deploy a Flutter Application using https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

when I paste the following command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

I keep getting `bash: keytool: command not found` I have followed alot of the answers provided and here is what I came up with:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

I have changed the Environment Path and here is the print screen:
[image]

MY Question what else should I change or update in order to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a full JDK. A JRE doesn't has developer tools like keytool.

Comment: I change the path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin` still same error

Comment: I also downloaded the latest: 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk20-windows

Comment: Are you using bash in Windows WSL? Have you restarted the terminal so it takes the environment change to the PATH variable?

Comment: Yes I am using Bash and I restarted the terminal

Comment: This is wrong. keytool is part of the JRE and has been since the beginning of Java. But it, and some other less-used things like rmid and kinit, are NOT put in the `javapath` shortcut by the Oracle Windows installers. For a j8 or lower JDK you need path `...\jdk<version>\jre\bin` not just `...\jdk<version>\bin`. (For j9 up this is no longer true; there is now only one bin directory for the combined JRE and JDK tools.)